# Modeling a constraint in GMPL

Tags: modeling, linear-programming, mathprog

I'm trying to model this constraint in GMPL.

[image: Constraint]

As far as I can understand, ***j:d<sub>ij</sub> < D<sup>k</sup>*** part means " all the 'j's which satisfies the property d<sub>ij</sub> < D<sup>k</sup> "

I'm pretty new to it so I couldn't manage to model it correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, did it this way:

```
s.t. c3{i in N, k in K} : z[k] + sum{j in M : d[i,j] < b[k]} y[j] >= 1;
```

"b" is used in case of "D".